# Force text length + trimming

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, binding

I'm using Bindings to populate a `Listbox`, with `TextBlock`s, etc.

**The question is :**

How do I make sure that the text bound to the the `Text` property of a `TextBlock` is of **specific length**, or that it is **displayed trimmed at some specific character length** (e.g. `"some very very long t..."`), so that the text doesn't "overflow" the phone screen or its container?

Comment: Have you tried playing around with the `FormatString` property? (I've seen this in winforms not sure if it exists outside but I presume so)

Comment: @Sayse Well, that's one of the first things that came to my mind, but I still can't figure out *how* to use it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Mango SDK, there is a property call [TextTrimming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.texttrimming%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

So this xaml

```
<TextBlock Text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Width="200" />
```

will produce somehting like *"aaaaaaa....."*

Comment: I didn't see such property there for a textbox. There is other go for a textbox. But this goes well for a textblock. Good one!

Comment: Yep, you got it right. I had already added the `TextTrimming` property, though what I was missing was setting the `Width` (or a `MaxWidth` for that matter) too. Thanks a lot, buddy! :-)

Comment: @max I wasn't talking about a `TextBox`. What I needed was trimming/truncation for `TextBlock`s. :-)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon Exactly thats were i was mistaken for!

Answer (score 1):

Tricky one! I forced myself to think that if the characters exceeds, say some 10 then i am going to append dots to it. So i added this textchanged event to the textbox and then made the code as follows:

```
private void TestTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
        string temp = TestTextBox.Text;
        if (temp.Length > 10)
        {
            char[] charArray=temp.ToCharArray();
            temp = new string(charArray, 0, 10);
            temp += "...";
        }
        TestTextBox.Text = temp;
}
```

Comment: Nice try and a pretty valuable piece of code - even though for `TextBox`es.

Comment: You could just do `string.Remove(10);`